# Multiplying algebraic terms problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Today I have this problem to solve (I already know the answer though, because I cheated by looking it up):

The area of a rectangle is equal to x^2 + 9x + 18.  If the length of one side is 2x+6 , what is then the length of the second side? (The answer, that I looked up, is 0.5x + 3).

Here's the thing: I already know that the answer makes sense because I already know how to multiply algebraic terms. What I need help with, is how to find out these answers. How do I end up with the answer 0.5x + 3 ? Do I just "think" of what 2x needs to be multiplied with in order to be x^2 ? And then think about what 6 needs to be multiplied with in order to be 18? But how do I know where I'll get the 9x from ?

Huge thanks for any anwers trying to tell me what strategy you need to have in your mind when first meeting these kind of math problems!

Comment: Well, if you know that $2x+6$ is one of the side lengths, you could just use polynomial long division to get the other side length. This is a sure strategy in this context.

Using your strategy, the $9x$ will appear naturally. $(2x+6)(\frac x2+3)$ doesn't have any indication of producing a $9x$ but I think you can see that your guess must work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others will probably answer with more rigorous ways (long division), but I think you can make some educated guesses by first recognizing that the answer should be a polynomial of degree 1, $ax+b$. So then you need to match

$$(ax + b)(2x+6) = x^2 + 9x + 18$$

Reducing the left hand side,

$$2ax^2 +6ax+ 2bx +6b =x^2 + 9x + 18$$

Then match the terms of degree 2 and 0. We need $2a=1$ for $2ax^2$ to match $x^2$, and then $6b=18$. That gives $a=.5$ and $b=3$.

Comment: Hey, I found your answer to be of great help. Here's what I found though, if the math problem was: "The rectangle area = 15x^2 + something + 25. One side = 3x + 5. What is the other side?", then you could simply calculate what the 3x needed to multiply with in order to be 15x^2  and what 5 needed to multiply with in order to be 25. (3x+5)(5x+5) = 15x^2 + 40x + 25. But your answer helped me understand the base knowledge, thanks.